# Links aren't working

Tags: php, html, captcha, recaptcha

I'm not sure what is happening to my contact form on my page- ["We Can Help."](http://0350498.netsolhost.com/contact.php) I watched the tutorial series from [Dream Weaver Tutorial](http://www.dreamweavertutorial.co.uk/), and I tried to tie in reCAPTCHA and [Hot Dreamweaver](http://hotdreamweaver.com/)'s add-on.

Does anyone know why the navigation and the header picture and the Adobe picture don't show?

Comment: the CSS is missing? did your server has GD support? CAPTCHA often requires this PHP extension

Answer (score 2):

You are using absolute addresses to your links and resources to places that only exist on your local machine. Instead use relative addresses in your html.

Example.

Instead of this html:

```
<img src="file:///I|/Town_Monitoring_Website/images/Logo copy.jpg" width="213" height="75" border="none" />
```

Do this:

```
<img src="images/Logo copy.jpg" width="213" height="75" border="none" />
```

You want to remove all of these references in your html

```
file:///I|/Town_Monitoring_Website/
```

Comment: This will fix your problem!!

Answer (score 0):

All of your image sources and links are pointing to a local file system they need to be either absolute or relative paths. I updated the code on your page to reflect relative paths as long as the file names and images are in the correct directories this will be working code just copy and paste:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<!-- Contact Form Designed by James Brand @ dreamweavertutorial.co.uk -->
<!-- Covered under creative commons license - http://dreamweavertutorial.co.uk/permissions/contact-form-permissions.htm -->

    <title>Towne Monitoring Service/FAQ's</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="contact/css/contactform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/css style sheet template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
var nameError = 'Please enter a Name to proceed.';
        var phoneError = 'Please enter a valid Phone Number to continue.';
        var addressError = 'Please enter a valid Maling Address to continue.';
        var emailError = 'Please enter a valid Email Address to continue.';
        var commentError = 'Please enter your Message to continue.';
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
    </script>

    </head>

<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/x.png')">

<div id="container">
<div id="header"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/Logo copy.jpg" width="213" height="75" border="none" /></a></div><!-- end div header -->

  <div id="nav">
<ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ's</a></li>
      <li><a href="did_you_know.html">Did You Know?</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">We Can Help</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div><!-- end dic nav -->
<div id="content">
  <table width="1000" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="574">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="312">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><div id="for mWrap">
<div id="form">

<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="comments_form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Your Name</div>
    <!-- end .label -->
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" id="fullname" class="detail" name="fullname" value="" />
          </div>
    <!-- end .input -->
    <div class="context">e.g. John Smith or Jane Doe</div>
    <!-- end .context -->
  </div>
  <!-- end .row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Your Email Address</div>
    <!-- end .label -->
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" id="email" class="detail" name="email" value="" />
          </div>
    <!-- end .input -->
    <div class="context">We will not share your email with anyone or spam you with messages either</div>
    <!-- end .context -->
  </div>
  <!-- end .row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Your Phone Number</div>
    <!-- end .label -->
    <div class="input">

      <input type="text" id="phone" class="detail" name="phone" value="" />

          </div>
    <!-- end .input -->
    <div class="context">(123)-123-1234</div>
    <!-- end .context -->
  </div>
  <!-- end .row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Your Address</div>
    <!-- end .label -->
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" id="address" class="detail" name="address" value="" />    </div>
    <!-- end .input -->
    <div class="context">e.g. 123 Cherry ln. Happyville P.A. 18999</div>
    <!-- end .context -->
  </div>
  <!-- end .row --><!-- end .row --><br />
  <br />

<div class="submit">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
</div>
<!-- end .submit -->
<input type="hidden" name="hdwfail" id="hdwfail" value="contact.php" />
</form>



</div><!-- edn #form -->
</div></td>
      <td valign="top"><div id="loads"><table width="198" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="192" height="143"><h2>Download's<img src=images/Downloads/Adobe-PDF-Logo.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></h2>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p><a href="http://getadobe.com/reader">Click here for Adobe Reader.</a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p><a href="images/Downloads/Personal Emergency Info.pdf">Information Sheet</a></p>
            <p>(.pdf size: 182k)</p>
            <p><a href="images/Downloads/Company Brochure.pdf">Company Brochure</a></p>
            <p>(.pdf size: 390k)</p>
            <p><a href="images/Downloads/medbro.pdf">Handling Emergencies</a></p>
            <p>(.pdf size: 143k)</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="67">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- end formWrap -->
</div>
<div id="apDiv7">
  <table width="1000" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="588"><h3>&copy; 2012 TOWNE MONITORING SERVICE, LP   ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</h3></td>
    <td width="77" align="right"><img src="images/csaa.jpg" width="74" height="40" /></td>
    <td width="336"><img src="images/footer2.jpg" width="334" height="40" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div><!-- end div7 -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```